# как сделать чтобы поток с++11 не висел?

Tags: многопоточность, c++11

здравствуйте, есть абстрактная задача: создаются три асинхронных нити, первая - управляющая - ждет 3 секунды, затем с помощью condition variable запускает вывод у двух ожидающих сигнала нитей:

```
namespace mutexes {
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cond;
std::atomic<bool> at = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

void thread_1() {
    while(true) {
        static int i = 0;
        std::cout<<"thread 1\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
        if(i==5)
            break;
        if(i++==2) {
            at = 1;
            cond.notify_all();
        }
    }
    at = 0;
}
void thread_2() {
    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cond.wait(lk,[]{ return at == 1;});
        std::cout<<"thread 2\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
void thread_3() {
    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cond.wait(lk,[]{ return at == 1;});
        std::cout<<"thread 3\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
}    //namespace mutexes

int main() {
//запускаем все три потока асинхронно
std::thread([]{
            std::thread thrd1(&mutexes::thread_1);
            std::thread thrd2(&mutexes::thread_2);
            std::thread thrd3(&mutexes::thread_3);
            thrd1.detach();
            thrd2.detach();
            thrd3.detach();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(6));
        }).join();
}
```

в итоге вывод идет только со второго(thread_2)... я не могу понять почему, видимо dead lock мьютекса... помогите сделать так, чтобы вывод в консоль шел с обоих потоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам отвечаю на свой вопрос... получился вывод с двух потоков только так:

```
namespace mutexes {
std::mutex m1;
std::mutex m2;
std::condition_variable_any cond;
std::atomic<bool> at = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

void thread_1() {
while(true) {
    static int i = 0;
    std::cout<<"thread 1\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if(i==5)
        break;
    if(i++==2) {
        at = 1;
        cond.notify_all();
    }
}
at = 0;
}

void thread_2() {
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m1);
while(true) {
    cond.wait(lk,[]{ return at == 1;});
    std::cout<<"thread 2\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
}

void thread_3() {
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m2);
while(true) {    
    cond.wait(lk,[]{ return at == 1;});
    std::cout<<"thread 3\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
}
}
}    //namespace mutexes

int main() {
//запускаем все три потока асинхронно
std::thread([]{
        std::thread thrd1(&mutexes::thread_1);
        std::thread thrd2(&mutexes::thread_2);
        std::thread thrd3(&mutexes::thread_3);
        thrd1.detach();
        thrd2.detach();
        thrd3.detach();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(6));
    }).join();
}
```

платформа linux_x86_64... был бы рад если б кто-нибудь объяснил бы почему работает только с std::condition_variable_any а не с std::condition_variable

Comment: Не знаю, как многопоточность (разные типы cond) реализована в крестах, но подозреваю, что в основе (в Linux) лежат pthreads. Почитайте [man pthread_cond_signal](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) (др. man pthread_... тоже стоит почитать) и обратите внимание на раздел `Rationale
Multiple Awakenings by Condition Signal`. Видимо подходящий алгоритм реализован только для типа `std::condition_variable_any`

Comment: Вообще-то не уверен, что код в ответе правильный, поскольку Вы используете 2 разных mutex (m1 и m2) с одной и той же переменной cond. Да и thread1 вызывает notify, не захватив ни один из этих mutex. В `man pthread_cond_signal` пишут -- "*if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal().*"

Comment: благодарствую за ответ

Answer (score 1):

В вашем исходном коде проблема в том, что оба потока требуют блокировку на одном и том же мьютексе для работы - поэтому в каждый момент времени может работать только один. Почему бы "этому одному" не быть каждый раз потоком номер 2? Совершенно корректное поведение.

Вам, наверное, следовало бы после получения задания освободить блокировку, чтобы потоки смогли работать одновременно:

```
void thread_2() {
    while(true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            cond.wait(lk,[]{ return at == 1;});
        }
        std::cout<<"thread 2\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

---

PS Почему потоки 2 и 3 не могут быть запущены не сразу, а потоком 1 после истечения времени ожидания? Это бы все упростило.

Comment: хм, если делать вашим методом, то получится только один раз известить 2 и 3 потоки, а мне нужно чтобы в зависимости от управляемого потока они то ожидали - то работали... ну вот, допустим, веб-сервер какой-нибудь: он же все время должен ожидать т.е. там внутри цикла уже должно все твориться, а не цикл отдельно... возможно есть какие то паттерны как грамотно это реализовывать?

а по истечении времени ожидания запускать потоки не получится т.к. это совсем другая задача, а мне нужно именно запускать, потом как бы "приостанавливать", а потом снова запускать

Comment: @xperious переписал чтобы ждал каждый раз. Но аналогия с веб-сервером кривая - там используются другие механизмы (обычно каждый рабочий поток просто ждет на сокете).

Comment: @xperious вам же могу посоветовать почитать про примитив синхронизации "очередь" и про стандартную задачу "поставщик-потребитель" (producer-consumer)

Comment: честно говоря так и не вышло вашим исправленным способом чтобы с одного мьютекса работало(хотя странно, по идее, должно работать)... только с двух разных. но за идею спасибо...
а не, кажись, все правильно, благодарствую за ответ